# store in different arrays java beginner

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, methods, polymorphism

like the title says I'm a beginner in Java and I'm currently working on a project in school where I store animals in a zoo and display their sound. 
This is my `Zoo` class:

```
public final class Zoo {

    private Animal[] animals;
    private int nextIndex;

    public Zoo() {
        animals = new Animal[5];
        nextIndex = 0;
    }

    public void addAnimal(Animal animal) {

        if (animal instanceof DangerousAnimal) {
            System.out.println(animal.getAnimalName() + " is dangerous. We don't store dangerous animals in our zoo!");
            return;
        }

        if (doesAnimalExist(animal)) {
            System.out.println(animal.getAnimalName() + " already exists in storage. Can't store it twice!");
        } else {

            if (nextIndex >= animals.length) {
                animals = Arrays.copyOf(animals, animals.length + 5);
            }
            animals[nextIndex] = animal;
            nextIndex++;

        }

    }

    public void hearAnimalSound() {

        for (Animal aniTemp : animals) {
            if (aniTemp == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(aniTemp.getAnimalName() + ": " + aniTemp.sound());

        }
    }

    public boolean doesAnimalExist(Animal animalAdd) {

        for (Animal animal : animals) {
            if (animalAdd.equals(animal)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now I need to store my animals in two different arrays, domestic and wild, and I don't know how to do this.

I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
public class AnimalStorage {

   private Animal[] animals;

   public void addAnimal(Animal animal) {

   }
}

public class Zoo {

   private AnimalStorage domesticAnimals;

private AnimalStorage wildAnimals;



public void addAnimal(Animal animal) {

   }

}
```

but, what do I implement in the `addAnimal` methods for respective class? Or should I do it in another way? 
I'm kind of lost here. I appreciate all the help I can get.
Thanks!
David

@ajb Sorry, here is my Animal class and subclasses:

public abstract class Animal {

```
private final String animalName;

public Animal(String animalName) {
    this.animalName = animalName;
}

public abstract String sound();

public String getAnimalName() {
    return animalName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return animalName;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object otherAnimal) {
    if (otherAnimal != null && this.getClass().equals(otherAnimal.getClass())) {
        Animal animal = (Animal) otherAnimal;

        return this.animalName.equals(animal.animalName);
    }
    return false;

}
```

}

public final class Bear extends Animal implements DangerousAnimal {

```
public Bear(String animalName) {
    super(animalName);
}

@Override
public String sound() {
    return "Wraaaaaar!";
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.getAnimalName();
}
```

}

public final class Monkey extends Animal {

```
public Monkey(String animalName) {
    super(animalName);
}

@Override
public String sound() {
    return "Ooooh ooh aaah aaah!";
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getAnimalName();
}
```

}

The rest of the animals are the same..

My main looks like this:

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Zoo zoo = new Zoo();

    zoo.addAnimal(new Bear("Baloo the Bear"));
    zoo.addAnimal(new Lion("Simba the Lion"));
    zoo.addAnimal(new Snake("Kaa the Snake"));
    zoo.addAnimal(new Monkey("Abu the Monkey"));
    zoo.addAnimal(new Bird("Tweety the Bird"));
    zoo.addAnimal(new Donkey("I-or the Donkey"));

    zoo.hearAnimalSound();

    System.out.println();
    zoo.addAnimal(new Donkey("I-or the Donkey"));
}
```

}

Comment: Without seeing the `Animal` class and subclasses, or at least having information about what those are and what methods they support, I doubt anyone can really give you any help.

Comment: Sorry for that! I edited my post, now you can see my Animal class, subclasses and main. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the Zoo class you can (I assume you have Domestic and Wild subclasses of animal):

```java
public void addAnimal(Animal animal) {
  if(animal instanceof DomesticAnimal)
    domesticStorage.addAnimal(animal);
  else
    wildStorage.addAnimal(animal)
}
```

And in AnimalStorage just:

`animals[currentIndex++] = animal;`

If you don't want duplicates you need to take care of that, same way you did in your Zoo class. Also I suggest using `ArrayList` instead of array, you are extending your array by yourself by copying, but why do that if you can just use `ArrayList`? You probably don't know there is something like that, so I'm telling you now. You do it like this:

`List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();`

And you can just add Animal objects to it as long as you want, it will extend itself, you can also remove them, set them by index, get them by index etc., check this: [ArrayList doc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Hi, the reason I don't use ArrayList is that this is a school assignment and we are not allowed to use it. I edited my post so now you can see my Animal class, subclasses and main. thanks!

Comment: But you want to store `domestic` and `wild` animals, you have interfaces for those? If not then how you want to determine if animal is domestic or wild?